# Extjs 4.x - CheckboxModel to get checked and unchecked value

Tags: extjs4, selectionmodel

I have used check box model in the grid panel. When i checked the check box i am the checked column value. Now what i need is when i unchecked i need to get that same unchecked value.

```
var selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    checkOnly: true,
    listeners: {
        selectionchange: function(model, records) {
            if (records[0]) {
                id = records[0].get('id');
                alert(id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Riyaz

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer:

```
var selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    checkOnly: true,
    listeners: {
        deselect: function(model, record, index) {
            id = record.get('id');
            alert(id);
        },
        select: function(model, record, index) {
            id = record.get('id');
            alert(id);
        }
    }
})
```